# How to display ckeditor 5 content from database with the same css style

Tags: ckeditor, text-editor, ckeditor5

When the user finish writing in the "ckeditor 5" I take the html input and store it in database:

[image]

The content will be saved in database as text:
`<blockquote><p>Hello <strong>world</strong></p></blockquote><p>&nbsp;</p><figure class="table"><table><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table></figure>`

Now when I get this content from database and I want to show it in the front-end, It shows up like this:

[image]

How to make the text css style the same as how the user has entered in the "ckeditor 5" ?

Comment: how do you display the data? Can you include the code for displaying the data from db.

Answer (score 0):

According to laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data)

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. **If you do not
>   want your data to be escaped**, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to duplicate the editor styles.
All editor have base class and styles for content inside that class.

for ckeditor5 for exmaple that class  'ck-content'.

From the docs https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/content-styles.html

> Important!
>
> If you take a closer look at the content styles, you may notice they
> are prefixed with the .ck-content class selector. This narrows their
> scope when used in CKEditor 5 so they do not affect the rest of the
> application. To use them in the front–end, you will have to add the
> ck-content CSS class to the container of your content. Otherwise the
> styles will not be applied.

Finally, using **WYSIWYG** (What You See Is What You Get) editors you should ovveride the editor styles config to provide same styles for the editor and for wrapped display content with same class.
Otherwise, the final solution will not be WYSIWYG.

Answer (score -3):

**Solution 1:**

Install bootstrap on display.php
https://getbootstrap.com/

**Solution 2**
You need to apply CSS manually on the display page.

HTML from database on (for example) display.php:

```
<blockquote><p>Hello <strong>world</strong></p></blockquote><p>&nbsp;</p><figure class="table"><table><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table></figure>
```

Write CSS on display.php like:

```
<style>
table tr td{
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ckeditor is a WYSIWYG editing solution, you don't really need to manually add css to display what has been saved in your db. You just need to display it directly with unescaped html.

Comment: Only HTML was saved in DB. When you echo they show only HTML. For that, you need to apply CSS where you are putting echo.

Comment: Actually, if you have an experience working with any WYSIWYG editing solution, you should know that every WYSIWYG plugin has their own css class/styling. They will add it automatically depending on the style of your WYSIWYG content. Again, you don't need to add css/style manually because it defeats the purpose of the WYSIWYG plugin.